# Специализация шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс:

```
template <typename T>
class CSerializer {
public:
    void write(std::ostream &stream, const T &value) const;
    void  read(std::istream &stream, T &value) const;
};
```

Предполагается, что инстанцирование объектов данного класса будет выполняться только для PDT типов (int, unsigned, char и т.п.).

Для остальных типов предполагается наличие специализаций данного класса, например, для типа `std::string`:

```
template <>
class CSerializer<std::string> {
public:
    void write(std::ostream &stream, const std::string &str) const;
    void  read(std::istream &stream, std::string &str) const;
};
```

Далее. У нас есть интерфейс `ISerializable`:

```
class ISerializable {
public:
    virtual ~ISerializable() = default;

public:
    virtual void    write_binary(std::ostream &stream) const = 0;
    virtual void     read_binary(std::istream &stream) = 0;

    virtual size    serialized_size() const noexcept = 0;
};
```

, а так же множество классов, которые от него наследуются. Я хотел специализировать класс `CSerializer` для типа `ISerializable`, вроде:

```
template <>
class CSerializer<ISerializable> {
public:
    void write(std::ostream &stream, const ISerializable &obj) const;
    void  read(std::istream &stream, ISerializable &obj) const;
};
```

И это не заработало :) Почему не заработало - я понимаю. Вопрос: можно ли написать такую специализацию класса `CSerializer`, которая бы инстанцировалась, когда T - класс-наследник `ISerializable`?

---

Я знаю как это сделать через ф-ию, вроде:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
CSerializer<T>* make_serializer() { ... }

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of< ... >>::value>
CSerializer<ISerializable>* make_serializer() { ... }
```

Но пусть это будет "запасным" вариантом.

---

UPD: подсказали, что в C++20 для этого идеально подходят концепты. Создал еще [один вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878032/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c17).

Comment: А можете пояснить, почему не заработало? У меня вот так вот работает.

Comment: Автор хочет одну специализацию для всех наследников `ISerializable`, а не для самого этого класса.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо :) Это очень точная формулировка, так что мне нечего добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все точно так же, как с функцией:

```
template <typename T, typename Void = void>
class CSerializer
{
    static_assert(std::is_void_v<Void>);
    ...
};

template <typename T>
class CSerializer<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<ISerializable, T>>>
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: Мне не хотелось бы вводить дополнительный параметр в шаблон, собственно, поэтому я и написал, что можно реализовать желаемое поведение с помощью ф-ии ```make_serializer``` - тогда второй параметр появится только у этой ф-ии. Однако, я еще не знаю, как сделать лучше. Попробую, спасибо. На данный момент Ваш ответ наиболее подходит для описанной ситуации.

Comment: Друзья, пожалуйста, если ставите минус - объясняйте, по какой причине. Может действительно что-то не так - лично мне это было бы полезно знать, другим, думаю, так же.

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант, можно сделать:

```
template<typename _T>
using SerializerType = CSerializer<typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<ISerializable, _T>::value, ISerializable, _T>::type>;
```

Comment: Извините, но я не совсем понимаю, как я смогу это использовать. Смотрите, я хочу использовать CSerializer внутри другого шаблонного класса, если я здесь не смогу написать "общий код" - т.е. писать CSerializer<T> (а там уже пусть само разруливает), то мне и для этого нового класса придется писать дополнительный код, аналогичный тому, который Вы сейчас привели. Не исключено, что я просто не до конца понял Вашу идею. В таком случае - дополните объяснением.